# Working with git via crontab

Tags: ubuntu, shell, git, cron, crontab

I have the following shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
REPODIR=$HOME/work/repository/
cd $REPODIR
var=`git fetch --dry-run 2>&1`
echo $var > $HOME/error.txt
```

I want to run my script every minute, so I edit crontab (via `crontab -e`) in order to run script from the current user.

```
*/1 * * * * /home/nameoftheuser/Documents/report-server.sh
```

From manual run - script works correctly. But running script from crontab (in the error.txt):

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Script file has 775 rights. I'm also checked `git status` and `git config -l` and that commands work correctly. `git config -l` correctly display remote origin url. Ubuntu 13.04 x64 with latest updates.

What should I do to work with git from crontab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git can't authorize when asking remote about changes in master because when I generate ssh-key I protect it with a passphrase.

So I just regenerate key without passphrase and script works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

make crontab job as:

```
*/1 * * * * nameoftheuser /home/nameoftheuser/Documents/./report-server.sh
```

or

```
*/1 * * * * nameoftheuser sh /home/nameoftheuser/Documents/report-server.sh
```

Or if you want to do it as you posted, you need to add `alias` at the end of `/etc/bash.bashrc` to that script like:

```
alias report-server='/home/nameoftheuser/Documents/./report-server.sh'
```

and then you can add cron job as:

```
*/1 * * * * root report-server
```

Comment: None of these approaches doesn't work. They doesn't even create ```error.txt``` in the Home folder.
I need to execute script as user

Comment: make sure you do `/etc/init.d/cron restart` after every change to cron

Comment: Oh, sorry. I just realized that problem is not in the crontab. Somehow git can't authorize when asking remote about changes in master.

Comment: Oh then I shell delete this :)